# Saving data on click on local storage

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi guys just asking why I can't save my text value of `.comp-abbr` class. My goal is when I click the save button it will show the in `.iresult` class. Can anyone help me with how to do it? Thanks in advance. Also can anyone tell me what is my mistake here.

My code:

```js
$(".comp-abbr").on("click", function() {
    $(".comp-abbr").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
});

$(".saveBtn").on("click", function(){
    var abbr = $('.active').find('.comp-abbr').text();
    localStorage.setItem('test', abbr);
    $(".iresult").html(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comp-abbr active">Value One</div>
<div class="comp-abbr">Value Two</div>
<div class="comp-abbr">Value Three</div>

<div class="saveBtn">Click me</div>

<div class="iresult"></div>
```

Comment: Is test defined at all?

Comment: hi Tiko I've set the test to the key so all the abbr text value should apply there

Comment: let test = localStorage.getItem('test') try this

Comment: hi Tiko when I tried it's working however I need to click the button twice to get the value also when I tried refreshing the page it's still getting back to empty

Comment: Please see it here https://jsfiddle.net/ricobenviaje11/6nxyzpfd/

Comment: Change `$(".iresult").html(test);` to `$(".iresult").html(abbr);`

Comment: IF you want to show it on load, you can do `$(function() { const abbr = localStorage.getItem('test'); if (abbr) $(".iresult").html(abbr); });`

Comment: hi thanks for this looking into i now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with jQuery but the following should, with luck, work. The css was just ao help visualise which elelements were which but the only change was the call to `find` using both classes and adding the value from thr localStorage to the display output

```js
$(".comp-abbr").on("click", function() {
    $(".comp-abbr").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
});

$(".saveBtn").on("click", function(){
    var abbr = $(document).find('.active.comp-abbr').text();

    localStorage.setItem('test', abbr);
    $(".iresult").html( localStorage.getItem('test') );
});
```

```css
div{padding:0.5rem;margin:0.5rem;border:1px solid grey}
.saveBtn{color:red}
.iresult{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="comp-abbr active">Value One</div>
<div class="comp-abbr">Value Two</div>
<div class="comp-abbr">Value Three</div>

<div class="saveBtn">Click me</div>
<div class="iresult"></div>
```

Comment: Why get the item you just save from localStorage, that is a waste... Seems the error is solved just by changing `$(".iresult").html(test);` to `$(".iresult").html(abbr);`

Comment: purely in this case to show that it was stored. I agree the value is already known so there is no need to do so

Comment: I vote to close the question as a typo-type question